# Criando aplicativo que rode em background

Tags: android

Alguns aplicativos famosos, dentre eles Facebook, WhatsApp, Hangouts, usam um serviço rodando em background que não se encerra mesmo com o desligar/ligar do dispositivo.

A minha dúvida é em como desenvolver um aplicativo com essa característica? Alguém pode criar um exemplo básico que demonstre esse conceito?

Comment: O cara faz um pergunta e não volta pra marcar como resolvida e abandona o stackoverflow....

Comment: http://www.thiengo.com.br/service-android-entendendo-e-utilizando No seu caso veja este material, ele ensina a retomar o service usando broadcast...
agora no caso se vc quiser guardar valores ou coisa do genero apos a reinicialização, tera de utilizar o SQLite armazenando la tudo o que precisar para quando voltar a rodar a aplicação

Answer (score 12):

Este exemplo mostra como você pode minimizar sua atividade e iniciar um serviço e retomar a sua atividade sempre que necessário.

1. Crie um novo projeto *File* » *New* e nomeie o projeto para **BackgroundAppExample**.
2. Escreva o seguinte em **main.xml**:

   ```
   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/textView1"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
       android:layout_centerVertical="true"
       android:padding="@dimen/padding_medium"
       android:text="@string/hello_world"
       tools:context=".BackgroundAppExample" />

   <Button
       android:id="@+id/button1"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
       android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView1"
       android:layout_marginRight="49dp"
       android:layout_marginTop="74dp"
       android:text="Start Service" />
   ```
3. Escreva seguinte no arquivo de manifesto:

   ```java
   <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   package="com.example.backgroundappexample"
   android:versionCode="1"
   android:versionName="1.0" >

   <uses-sdk
       android:minSdkVersion="8"
       android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

   <application
       android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
       android:label="@string/app_name"
       android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
       <activity
           android:name=".BackgroundAppExample"
           android:label="@string/title_activity_background_app_example" >
           <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

               <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
           </intent-filter>
       </activity>
       <service android:enabled="true" android:name=".BackgroundService" />
   </application>
   ```
4. Criar e escrever o seguinte em **src/BackgroundService.java**:

   ```java
   package com.example.backgroundappexample;

   import android.app.Notification;
   import android.app.NotificationManager;
   import android.app.PendingIntent;
   import android.app.Service;
   import android.content.Intent;
   import android.os.Binder;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.os.IBinder;

   public class BackgroundService extends Service {
       private NotificationManager mNM;
   Bundle b;
   Intent notificationIntent;
   private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();
   private String newtext;

   public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
       BackgroundService getService() {
           return BackgroundService.this;
       }
   }

   @Override
   public void onCreate() {
       mNM = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

       newtext = "BackGroundApp Service Running";

       Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, newtext,System.currentTimeMillis());
       PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(BackgroundService.this, 0, new Intent(BackgroundService.this,   BackgroundAppExample.class), 0);
       notification.setLatestEventInfo(BackgroundService.this,"BackgroundAppExample", newtext, contentIntent);
       mNM.notify(R.string.local_service_started, notification);
       notificationIntent = new Intent(this, BackgroundAppExample.class);
       showNotification();     
   }

   public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
       return START_STICKY;
   }
   public void onDestroy() {
       mNM.cancel(R.string.local_service_started);
       stopSelf();
   }
   private void showNotification() {
       CharSequence text = getText(R.string.local_service_started);

       Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, text, System.currentTimeMillis());
       PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,new Intent(this, BackgroundAppExample.class), 0);
       notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, "BackgroundAppExample",newtext, contentIntent);
       notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT | Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;     
       notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

       mNM.notify(R.string.local_service_started, notification);
   }
   @Override
   public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
       return mBinder;
    }
   }
   ```
5. Execute!

---

Agora siga os seguintes passos:

1. Crie um projeto chamado **BackgroundAppExample** e defina as informações como indicado na imagem.

   ```
    Build Target: Android 4.0
    Application Name: BackgroundAppExample
    Package Name: com. example. BackgroundAppExample
    Activity Name: BackgroundAppExample
    Min SDK Version: 8
   ```

   [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
2. Abra o arquivo **BackgroundAppExample.java** e escreva seguinte código lá:

   ```java
   package com.example.backgroundappexample;

   import android.app.Activity;
   import android.content.Intent;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.view.Menu;
   import android.view.View;
   import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
   import android.widget.Button;
   import android.widget.TextView;

   public class BackgroundAppExample extends Activity {

   public static boolean isService = false; 
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.main);

       Button startserviceButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
       startserviceButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               startService(new Intent(BackgroundAppExample.this,BackgroundService.class));
               Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
               startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
               startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
               startActivity(startMain);
               isService = true;
           }
       });
   }

   @Override
   protected void onResume() {
       super.onResume();
       stopService(new Intent(BackgroundAppExample.this,
               BackgroundService.class));
       if(isService)
       {
           TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
           tv.setText("Service Resumed");
           isService = false;
       }
   }
   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
       getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
       return true;
    }
   }
   ```
3. Compile e execute.

Resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Essa resposta foi uma adaptação [**desse tutorial**](http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-development/background-app-example-in-android-programming/)(*escrito em inglês*).

Comment: O seu exemplo dá uma boa idéia do uso de serviços no Android, mas não é exatamente o que quero. Quero algo como um processo ininterrupto que não seja finalizado na reinicialização do sistema operacional, pois ficará escutando alguma alteração em um banco de dados remoto para avisar ao usuário. É semelhante a um mensageiro. Chegou uma mensagem emite um alerta.

Comment: Serviço ininterrupto não existe é claro. Mas acredito que dê pra configurar ele pra iniciar ao final do boot do celular. De uma olhada nessa pergunta do SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784441/trying-to-start-a-service-on-boot-on-android. Atenção: Talvez usar um serviço pra ficar gastando recurso seja um péssimo comportamento. De uma olhada no GCM da google.

Answer (score 1):

Eu estava com o mesmo problema e depois de muito tempo procurando a resposta e testando consegui usando `AlarmManager` e `BroadcastReceiver`, o que eu precisava:

Tenho um sistema web onde que alguém cadastra notificações no banco de dados, e uma API que retora um json com as requisições, eu precisava que alguma coisa ficasse executando com o app aberto ou fechado verificando se tem novas mensagens e notificando o usuário.

Meu `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<receiver
        android:name=".Servico.BootReciever"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="ALARME_DISPARADO2"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

No meu `onCreate` da *Activity*

```
boolean alarmeativo = (PendingIntent.getBroadcast( this, 0, new Intent( "ALARME_DISPARADO2" ), PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE ) == null);

        if(alarmeativo) {
            Intent intent = new Intent( "ALARME_DISPARADO2" );
            PendingIntent p = PendingIntent.getBroadcast( this, 0, intent, 0 );
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            c.setTimeInMillis( System.currentTimeMillis() );
            c.add( Calendar.SECOND, 3 );

            AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService( ALARM_SERVICE );
            alarm.set( AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, c.getTimeInMillis(), p );
        }
```

Verifico se o alarme já está criado, atribuo o `Intent` que vai ser executado referenciando ao meu `BroadcastReceiver`, atribuo um tempo para iniciar e configuro o alarme `RTC_WAKEUP` para executar mesmo com o aparelho blogueado, feito isso no `BroadcastReceiver` inicio uma *Task*, pois preciso dar um post em uma página na web, usando recursividade para continuar executando.

Meu `BootReciever.java`

```
public class BootReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {
public static Usuario us;
public static Notifi not;
public static NotifiSetor notSet;
public static Agenda notAg;

public static boolean Iniciar = true;
public static boolean saida;

int x = 0;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Iniciar = false;
        Usuario u = new Usuario( context );
        u.Select();
        us = u;

        Notifi n = new Notifi( context );
        not = n;

        NotifiSetor ns = new NotifiSetor(context );
        notSet = ns;

        Agenda ag = new Agenda( context );
        notAg = ag;

        NotificationTask us = new NotificationTask();
        us.execute(context);
}

public boolean isOnline(Context context) {
    boolean conectado;
    try {
        ConnectivityManager conectivtyManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService( Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE );
        if (conectivtyManager.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null
                && conectivtyManager.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable()
                && conectivtyManager.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected()) {
            conectado = true;
        } else {
            conectado = false;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        conectado = false;
    }
    return conectado;
}

private class NotificationTask extends AsyncTask<Context, Void, Context> {
    @Override
    protected Context doInBackground(Context... ct) {


        saida = false;
        try {
            Agenda a = new Agenda(notAg.getCt());
            List<Agenda> list = a.SelectExibir();
            if(list != null) {
                for (int x = 0; x < list.size(); x++) {
                    long date1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
                    String dateString = sdf.format(date1);
                    if(list.get(x).getExibir().equals(dateString)) {
                        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance( TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
                        Date currentLocalTime = cal.getTime();
                        DateFormat date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
                        date.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
                        String localTime = date.format(currentLocalTime);

                        NewMessageNotification.notify(ct[0], list.get(x).getTitulo(), list.get(x).getMensagem(), list.get(x).getID());
                        a.setID(list.get(x).getID());
                        a.setUltimo_Exib(localTime);
                        a.UpdateExibir();
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

        if(isOnline(ct[0])) {
            //Log.d("",String.valueOf( x++ ));
            // notificaçoes agendadas
            try {
                //buscar na api
                // buscar no webservice
                String json = "json a ser enviando para API";
                HttpService servi = new HttpService();
                String retorno = servi.post(json);

                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(retorno);
                    JSONArray array = jsonObj.getJSONArray("Res");
                    if (jsonObj.getBoolean("Response")) {

                        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                            // notificacao
                            notAg.setID(array.getJSONObject(i).getInt("ID"));
                            if (!notAg.ValidaId()) {
                                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
                                //cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -1);
                                Date currentLocalTime = cal.getTime();
                                DateFormat date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
                                date.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
                                String localTime = date.format(currentLocalTime);

                                notAg.setTitulo(array.getJSONObject(i).getString("TITULO"));
                                notAg.setMensagem(array.getJSONObject(i).getString("MENSAGEM"));
                                notAg.setCadastro(array.getJSONObject(i).getString("DATA_CAD"));
                                notAg.setExibir(array.getJSONObject(i).getString("REPETIR"));
                                notAg.setUltimo_Exib(localTime);
                                notAg.setStatus(array.getJSONObject(i).getInt("STATUS"));
                                notAg.Insert();
                            } else {
                                notAg.setTitulo(array.getJSONObject(i).getString("TITULO"));
                                notAg.setMensagem(array.getJSONObject(i).getString("MENSAGEM"));
                                notAg.setCadastro(array.getJSONObject(i).getString("DATA_CAD"));
                                notAg.setExibir(array.getJSONObject(i).getString("REPETIR"));
                                notAg.setStatus(array.getJSONObject(i).getInt("STATUS"));
                                notAg.Update();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // Restore interrupt status.
                //Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }

            // notificaçoes geral equipe
            try {
                //buscar na api
                // buscar no webservice
                String json = "json a ser enviando para API";
                HttpService servi = new HttpService();
                String retorno = servi.post(json);

                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(retorno);
                    JSONArray array = jsonObj.getJSONArray("Res");
                    if (jsonObj.getBoolean("Response")) {

                        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                            // notificacao
                            not.setID(array.getJSONObject(i).getInt("ID"));
                            if (!not.ValidaId()) {
                                not.setTitulo(array.getJSONObject(i).getString("TITULO"));
                                not.setMensagem(array.getJSONObject(i).getString("MENSAGEM"));
                                not.setData(array.getJSONObject(i).getString("DATA_CAD"));
                                not.setStatus(array.getJSONObject(i).getInt("STATUS"));
                                not.Insert();
                                NewMessageNotification.notify(ct[0], not.getTitulo(), not.getMensagem(), not.getID());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // Restore interrupt status.
                //Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }

            // notificaçoes geral setor
            try {
                //buscar na api
                // buscar no webservice
                String json = "json a ser enviando para API";
                HttpService servi = new HttpService();
                String retorno = servi.post(json);

                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(retorno);
                    JSONArray array = jsonObj.getJSONArray("Res");
                    if (jsonObj.getBoolean("Response")) {

                        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                            // notificacao
                            notSet.setID(array.getJSONObject(i).getInt("ID"));
                            if (!notSet.ValidaId()) {
                                notSet.setTitulo(array.getJSONObject(i).getString("TITULO"));
                                notSet.setMensagem(array.getJSONObject(i).getString("MENSAGEM"));
                                notSet.setData(array.getJSONObject(i).getString("DATA_CAD"));
                                notSet.setStatus(array.getJSONObject(i).getInt("STATUS"));
                                notSet.Insert();
                                NewMessageNotification.notify(ct[0], notSet.getTitulo(), notSet.getMensagem(), notSet.getID());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
                // exibir
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // Restore interrupt status.
                //Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
        }
        try { 
            // recursividade para continuar executando
            doInBackground( ct[0] );
        } catch(Exception e) {

        }
        return ct[0];
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Context result) {
        // Após a inserção da nota, vamos mostrar um Toast ao usuário
        saida = true;
        Iniciar = true;
        doInBackground(result);
    }
}
```

}

Resultado

```
I/art: Increasing code cache capacity to 128KB
D/14:46:36: -> Iniciado
D/14:46:41: -> Iniciado
D/14:46:42: -> Iniciado
D/14:46:44: -> Iniciado
D/14:46:45: -> Iniciado
D/14:46:46: -> Iniciado
D/14:46:48: -> Iniciado
D/14:46:49: -> Iniciado
D/14:46:50: -> Iniciado
D/14:46:52: -> Iniciado
D/14:46:53: -> Iniciado
D/14:46:54: -> Iniciado
D/14:46:56: -> Iniciado
D/14:46:56: -> Iniciado
D/14:46:57: -> Iniciado
D/14:46:58: -> Iniciado
D/14:46:59: -> Iniciado
D/14:47:00: -> Iniciado
D/14:47:01: -> Iniciado
D/14:47:03: -> Iniciado
D/14:47:04: -> Iniciado
D/14:47:07: -> Iniciado
D/14:47:09: -> Iniciado
D/14:47:11: -> Iniciado
D/14:47:12: -> Iniciado
D/14:47:15: -> Iniciado
D/14:47:16: -> Iniciado
D/14:47:17: -> Iniciado
D/14:47:18: -> Iniciado
D/14:47:19: -> Iniciado
D/14:47:20: -> Iniciado
D/14:47:21: -> Iniciado
D/14:47:22: -> Iniciado
D/14:47:23: -> Iniciado
D/14:47:24: -> Iniciado
D/14:47:25: -> Iniciado
D/14:47:26: -> Iniciado
D/14:47:27: -> Iniciado
D/14:47:28: -> Iniciado
D/14:47:30: -> Iniciado
D/14:47:32: -> Iniciado
D/14:47:33: -> Iniciado
D/14:47:34: -> Iniciado
D/14:47:35: -> Iniciado
D/14:47:36: -> Iniciado
D/14:47:37: -> Iniciado
D/14:47:38: -> Iniciado
D/14:47:38: -> Iniciado
D/14:47:39: -> Iniciado
D/14:47:40: -> Iniciado
D/14:47:41: -> Iniciado
D/14:47:42: -> Iniciado
D/14:47:43: -> Iniciado
D/14:47:43: -> Iniciado
D/14:47:44: -> Iniciado
D/14:47:45: -> Iniciado
D/14:47:46: -> Iniciado
D/14:47:46: -> Iniciado
D/14:47:47: -> Iniciado
D/14:47:48: -> Iniciado
D/14:47:49: -> Iniciado
D/14:47:50: -> Iniciado
I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 3085(212KB) AllocSpace objects, 2(40KB) LOS objects, 1% free, 28MB/28MB, paused 5.805ms total 16.525ms
D/14:47:50: -> Iniciado
D/14:47:51: -> Iniciado
D/14:47:52: -> Iniciado
D/14:47:53: -> Iniciado
D/14:47:54: -> Iniciado
D/14:47:55: -> Iniciado
D/14:47:56: -> Iniciado
D/14:47:57: -> Iniciado
D/14:47:58: -> Iniciado
D/14:47:58: -> Iniciado
D/14:47:59: -> Iniciado
D/14:48:00: -> Iniciado
D/14:48:01: -> Iniciado
D/14:48:02: -> Iniciado
D/14:48:02: -> Iniciado
D/14:48:03: -> Iniciado
D/14:48:04: -> Iniciado
D/14:48:05: -> Iniciado
D/14:48:06: -> Iniciado
D/14:48:07: -> Iniciado
D/14:48:09: -> Iniciado
D/14:48:10: -> Iniciado
D/14:48:11: -> Iniciado
D/14:48:12: -> Iniciado
D/14:48:13: -> Iniciado
D/14:48:13: -> Iniciado
D/14:48:14: -> Iniciado
D/14:48:15: -> Iniciado
D/14:48:16: -> Iniciado
D/14:48:17: -> Iniciado
D/14:48:18: -> Iniciado
D/14:48:19: -> Iniciado
D/14:48:20: -> Iniciado
D/14:48:21: -> Iniciado
D/14:48:22: -> Iniciado
D/14:48:22: -> Iniciado
Application terminated.
```

E testando no meu celular funcionou corretamente e com pouco tempo de *delay* para exibir as notificações com o aplicativo fechado e aberto, você pode também chamar um *Service* ou um *IntetService* no `onReceive`.