# Como enviar notificação sem abrir o aplicativo

Tags: android

preciso enviar uma notificação toda vez que alguém solicitar amizade. Como criar essa notificação eu ja sei mas fiz um app de teste que envia através da ação de um botão. Nesse caso o usuário que vai receber pode não estar com o app aberto. Como eu envio essa notificação? Faço uma thread que fica rodando a cada determinado horário?

Comment: A que tipo de notificação se está a referir? São aquelas que aparecem no *notification drawer*, na parte superior da tela?

Comment: Explique como/onde é o processo de "alguém solicitar amizade".

Comment: Inicialmente seria notificações que aparecem na tela mesmo. O processo do app é o seguinte, eu faço cadastro com fb, posso add pessoas que estão cadastradas, assim eu tenho uma lista de pessoas. Depois que eu listar essas pessoas eu posso add uma pessoa e ter uma amizade com ela. Nesse momento a pessoa que foi solicitada deve receber uma notificação.

Comment: Suponho que o quer é que a aplicação a correr no seu celular envie um notificação para a aplicação a correr em outro celular. Se é isso deverá utilizar o serviço *Google Cloud Messaging GCM*. Veja [aqui](http://androidexample.com/Device_To_Device_Messaging_Using_Google_Cloud_Messaging_GCM_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=122&aaid=142) um tutorial.

Comment: Outra possibilidade é utilizar o [Parse](https://parse.com/tutorials/android-push-notifications)

Answer (score 3):

O ideal é utilizar um **serviço** utilizando uma IntentService que fica verificando de tempos em tempos a necessidade de mostrar a notificação, é simples e prático. Quando utilizei a minha aplicação verificava dados em uma **WebApi** para então exibir a notificação.

```
package servicos;

import android.app.IntentService;
import android.content.Intent;

public class ServicoNotificacaoWebApi extends IntentService {

    private long plngIntervaloVerificacao;
    private boolean pblnServicoAtivo;

    /**
     * Construtor
     */
    public ServicoNotificacaoWebApi() {
        super("ServicoNotificacao");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

        pblnServicoAtivo = true;

        // Multiplicar por 1000, pois é em milisegundos
        plngIntervaloVerificacao = (intent.getLongExtra("INTERVALO_VERIFICACAO", 300)) * 1000;

        while (pblnServicoAtivo) {
            ConsultarWebApi();
        } 
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        // Ao encerrar o serviço, altera o flag para a thread parar
        pblnServicoAtivo = false;
    }

    /**
     * Verifica no web service se existem 
     * ordens de serviços disponíveis para a equipe
     */
    private void ConsultarWebApi() {
        try {

            // Tempo de espera até a próxima verificação no webapi
            Thread.sleep(plngIntervaloVerificacao); 

            if (!pblnServicoAtivo) {
                return;
            }

            // Não vou colocar o que eu faço para verificar a API para não ficar extenso, mais neste ponto eu exibo a notificação e no meu caso eu executo uma chamada para a tela de login de minha aplicação.
            if (WEBAPI_OK)
            ExibirNotificacao(this, "WEB_API", "Notificacao WebApi", 
                    "Mensagem", R.drawable.ic_launcher, 
                    9999, new Intent(this, ActLogin.class));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Caso seja necessário, colocar para gravar o log aqui
        }
    }

        /**
     * Exibe uma notificação
     * 
     * @param ctxContexto Contexto
     * @param strTituloNotificacao Título da notificação
     * @param strTituloMensagem Título da mensagem da notificação
     * @param strMensagem Mensagem
     * @param intIcone Ícone da notificação
     * @param intId Id da notificação (Necessário para cancelá-la)
     * @param intent Intent a ser disparada pela notificação
     */
    private void ExibirNotificacao(Context ctxContexto, String strTituloNotificacao, 
            String strTituloMensagem, String strMensagem, int intIcone, int intId, Intent intent) {

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) 
                ctxContexto.getSystemService(Activity.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Notification notification = new Notification(intIcone, strTituloNotificacao, System.currentTimeMillis());

        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | 
                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | 
                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND; // Som padrão da notificação
        notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL; // Cancela a notificação no clique 

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctxContexto, 0, intent, 0);

        notification.contentIntent = pendingIntent;

        notification.setLatestEventInfo(ctxContexto, strTituloMensagem, strMensagem, pendingIntent);
        notificationManager.notify(9999, notification);
    }
}
```

Para que seja chamado este IntentService deve ser adicionado ao Manifest.xml da sua aplicação:

```
<service
            android:name="servicos.ServicoNotificacaoWebApi"
            android:exported="false"
            android:process="servicos.ServicoNotificacaoWebApi" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="SERVICO_NOTIFICACAO_WEB_API" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
 </service>
```

E na hora de chamar é só chamar a Intent com o nome que voce colocou no Manifest.xml:

```
Intent lintentServico = new Intent("SERVICO_NOTIFICACAO_OS_AVULSA");        lintentServico.putExtra("INTERVALO_VERIFICACAO", 1);

// Inicia o serviço de notificação
pctxContexto.startService(lintentServico);
```

Comment: Tenho dúvidas se isso responde à pergunta. Quer responda ou não, é um mau exemplo para utilizar um serviço. Neste tipo de situação deve ser utilizado um AlarmManager, para gerir quando verificar a necessidade de lançar a notificação, juntamente com um *BroadcastReceiver*, para lançar a notificação.

Comment: ramaral, não conhecia este tipo de implementação, apesar de já ter utilizado o BroadcastReceiver. acredito que isso não justifica dar -1, se vc tem uma resposta melhor, publique-a.

Comment: Não posso responder porque a pergunta não está clara.

Comment: Se não pode responder, ok, mais dar -1 por uma implementação diferente da sua não é válido. Não estamos em uma competição, queremos é ajudar a comunidade.

Comment: Não leve a mal o -1, nada tem de pessoal,  apenas avaliei a sua resposta e considero que tal implementação é errada tendo em conta a forma de funcionamento do Android.  Pode não concordar mas negativar respostas ou perguntas também é ajudar a comunidade

Comment: Deixando de lado a questão do -1, ficar checando um servidor de tempos em tempos incorre em consumo desnecessário de banda e bateria e não é a melhor forma de se fazer. Para isso existem as _push notifications_ que avisam o aplicativo que existe algo novo no servidor, inclusive tendo a característica de iniciar o aplicativo caso ele não esteja em execução. No caso do Android procure conhecer o _Google Cloud Messaging_ como o @ramaral já citou.

Comment: Ta ai uma coisa que eu não sabia... fico no aguardo da resposta do @ramaral, pois, eu não conheço este recurso e com certeza faz sentido essa questão do consumo de banda e bateria. Valeu pela explicação Piovezan.

Comment: A pergunta é ampla de mais para se poder dar uma resposta, seria muito extensa. Se quiser saber mais sobre o *Parse* e o *Google Cloud Messaging(GCM)*  siga os links nos meus comentários à pergunta. O AlarmManager é disponibilizado pelo SDK para evitar que cada aplicação, que necessite de agendar tarefas, tenha de criar o seu próprio serviço. Havendo apenas um serviço, que pode ser utilizado por qualquer aplicação, reduz-se a quantidade necessária de recursos(memória, processador, bateria, etc) necessária à execução dessa tarefa.

Comment: O mesmo é aplicável ao GSM. Pense o que seria se cada aplicação, que necessitasse de comunicar com um serviço externo para obter qualquer tipo de *feedback*, tivesse o seu próprio serviço a correr no mesmo dispositivo.

Answer (score 0):

Olá, eu estava com o mesmo problema e depois de muito tempo procurando a resposta e testando consegui usando AlarmManager e BroadcastReceiver, o que eu precisava: 
Tenho um sistema web onde que alguém cadastra notificações no banco de dados, e uma API que retora um json com as requisições, eu precisava que alguma coisa ficasse executando com o app aberto ou fechado verificando se tem novas mensagens e notificando o usuário.


Meu **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<receiver
        android:name=".Servico.BootReciever"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="ALARME_DISPARADO2"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

No meu **onCreate** da Activity

```
boolean alarmeativo = (PendingIntent.getBroadcast( this, 0, new Intent( "ALARME_DISPARADO2" ), PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE ) == null);

        if(alarmeativo) {
            Intent intent = new Intent( "ALARME_DISPARADO2" );
            PendingIntent p = PendingIntent.getBroadcast( this, 0, intent, 0 );
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            c.setTimeInMillis( System.currentTimeMillis() );
            c.add( Calendar.SECOND, 3 );

            AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService( ALARM_SERVICE );
            alarm.set( AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, c.getTimeInMillis(), p );
        }
```

Verifico se o alarme já está criado, atribuo o Intent que vai ser executado referenciando ao meu BroadcastReceiver, atribuo um tempo para iniciar e configuro o alarme RTC_WAKEUP para executar mesmo com o aparelho blogueado, feito isso no BroadcastReceiver inicio uma Task, pois preciso dar um post em uma página na web, usando recursividade para continuar exebutando.


Meu **BootReciever.java**

```
public class BootReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {
public static Usuario us;
public static Notifi not;
public static NotifiSetor notSet;
public static Agenda notAg;

public static boolean Iniciar = true;
public static boolean saida;

int x = 0;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Iniciar = false;
        Usuario u = new Usuario( context );
        u.Select();
        us = u;

        Notifi n = new Notifi( context );
        not = n;

        NotifiSetor ns = new NotifiSetor(context );
        notSet = ns;

        Agenda ag = new Agenda( context );
        notAg = ag;

        NotificationTask us = new NotificationTask();
        us.execute(context);
}

public boolean isOnline(Context context) {
    boolean conectado;
    try {
        ConnectivityManager conectivtyManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService( Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE );
        if (conectivtyManager.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null
                && conectivtyManager.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable()
                && conectivtyManager.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected()) {
            conectado = true;
        } else {
            conectado = false;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        conectado = false;
    }
    return conectado;
}

private class NotificationTask extends AsyncTask<Context, Void, Context> {
    @Override
    protected Context doInBackground(Context... ct) {


        saida = false;
        try {
            Agenda a = new Agenda(notAg.getCt());
            List<Agenda> list = a.SelectExibir();
            if(list != null) {
                for (int x = 0; x < list.size(); x++) {
                    long date1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
                    String dateString = sdf.format(date1);
                    if(list.get(x).getExibir().equals(dateString)) {
                        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance( TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
                        Date currentLocalTime = cal.getTime();
                        DateFormat date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
                        date.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
                        String localTime = date.format(currentLocalTime);

                        NewMessageNotification.notify(ct[0], list.get(x).getTitulo(), list.get(x).getMensagem(), list.get(x).getID());
                        a.setID(list.get(x).getID());
                        a.setUltimo_Exib(localTime);
                        a.UpdateExibir();
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

        if(isOnline(ct[0])) {
            //Log.d("",String.valueOf( x++ ));
            // notificaçoes agendadas
            try {
                //buscar na api
                // buscar no webservice
                String json = "json a ser enviando para API";
                HttpService servi = new HttpService();
                String retorno = servi.post(json);

                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(retorno);
                    JSONArray array = jsonObj.getJSONArray("Res");
                    if (jsonObj.getBoolean("Response")) {

                        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                            // notificacao
                            notAg.setID(array.getJSONObject(i).getInt("ID"));
                            if (!notAg.ValidaId()) {
                                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
                                //cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -1);
                                Date currentLocalTime = cal.getTime();
                                DateFormat date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
                                date.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
                                String localTime = date.format(currentLocalTime);

                                notAg.setTitulo(array.getJSONObject(i).getString("TITULO"));
                                notAg.setMensagem(array.getJSONObject(i).getString("MENSAGEM"));
                                notAg.setCadastro(array.getJSONObject(i).getString("DATA_CAD"));
                                notAg.setExibir(array.getJSONObject(i).getString("REPETIR"));
                                notAg.setUltimo_Exib(localTime);
                                notAg.setStatus(array.getJSONObject(i).getInt("STATUS"));
                                notAg.Insert();
                            } else {
                                notAg.setTitulo(array.getJSONObject(i).getString("TITULO"));
                                notAg.setMensagem(array.getJSONObject(i).getString("MENSAGEM"));
                                notAg.setCadastro(array.getJSONObject(i).getString("DATA_CAD"));
                                notAg.setExibir(array.getJSONObject(i).getString("REPETIR"));
                                notAg.setStatus(array.getJSONObject(i).getInt("STATUS"));
                                notAg.Update();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // Restore interrupt status.
                //Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }

            // notificaçoes geral equipe
            try {
                //buscar na api
                // buscar no webservice
                String json = "json a ser enviando para API";
                HttpService servi = new HttpService();
                String retorno = servi.post(json);

                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(retorno);
                    JSONArray array = jsonObj.getJSONArray("Res");
                    if (jsonObj.getBoolean("Response")) {

                        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                            // notificacao
                            not.setID(array.getJSONObject(i).getInt("ID"));
                            if (!not.ValidaId()) {
                                not.setTitulo(array.getJSONObject(i).getString("TITULO"));
                                not.setMensagem(array.getJSONObject(i).getString("MENSAGEM"));
                                not.setData(array.getJSONObject(i).getString("DATA_CAD"));
                                not.setStatus(array.getJSONObject(i).getInt("STATUS"));
                                not.Insert();
                                NewMessageNotification.notify(ct[0], not.getTitulo(), not.getMensagem(), not.getID());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // Restore interrupt status.
                //Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }

            // notificaçoes geral setor
            try {
                //buscar na api
                // buscar no webservice
                String json = "json a ser enviando para API";
                HttpService servi = new HttpService();
                String retorno = servi.post(json);

                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(retorno);
                    JSONArray array = jsonObj.getJSONArray("Res");
                    if (jsonObj.getBoolean("Response")) {

                        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                            // notificacao
                            notSet.setID(array.getJSONObject(i).getInt("ID"));
                            if (!notSet.ValidaId()) {
                                notSet.setTitulo(array.getJSONObject(i).getString("TITULO"));
                                notSet.setMensagem(array.getJSONObject(i).getString("MENSAGEM"));
                                notSet.setData(array.getJSONObject(i).getString("DATA_CAD"));
                                notSet.setStatus(array.getJSONObject(i).getInt("STATUS"));
                                notSet.Insert();
                                NewMessageNotification.notify(ct[0], notSet.getTitulo(), notSet.getMensagem(), notSet.getID());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
                // exibir
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // Restore interrupt status.
                //Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
        }
        try { 
            // recursividade para continuar executando
            doInBackground( ct[0] );
        } catch(Exception e) {

        }
        return ct[0];
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Context result) {
        // Após a inserção da nota, vamos mostrar um Toast ao usuário
        saida = true;
        Iniciar = true;
        doInBackground(result);
    }
}
```

}

**Resultado**
I/art: Increasing code cache capacity to 128KB
D/14:46:36: -> Iniciado
D/14:46:41: -> Iniciado
D/14:46:42: -> Iniciado
D/14:46:44: -> Iniciado
D/14:46:45: -> Iniciado
D/14:46:46: -> Iniciado
D/14:46:48: -> Iniciado
D/14:46:49: -> Iniciado
D/14:46:50: -> Iniciado
D/14:46:52: -> Iniciado
D/14:46:53: -> Iniciado
D/14:46:54: -> Iniciado
D/14:46:56: -> Iniciado
D/14:46:56: -> Iniciado
D/14:46:57: -> Iniciado
D/14:46:58: -> Iniciado
D/14:46:59: -> Iniciado
D/14:47:00: -> Iniciado
D/14:47:01: -> Iniciado
D/14:47:03: -> Iniciado
D/14:47:04: -> Iniciado
D/14:47:07: -> Iniciado
D/14:47:09: -> Iniciado
D/14:47:11: -> Iniciado
D/14:47:12: -> Iniciado
D/14:47:15: -> Iniciado
D/14:47:16: -> Iniciado
D/14:47:17: -> Iniciado
D/14:47:18: -> Iniciado
D/14:47:19: -> Iniciado
D/14:47:20: -> Iniciado
D/14:47:21: -> Iniciado
D/14:47:22: -> Iniciado
D/14:47:23: -> Iniciado
D/14:47:24: -> Iniciado
D/14:47:25: -> Iniciado
D/14:47:26: -> Iniciado
D/14:47:27: -> Iniciado
D/14:47:28: -> Iniciado
D/14:47:30: -> Iniciado
D/14:47:32: -> Iniciado
D/14:47:33: -> Iniciado
D/14:47:34: -> Iniciado
D/14:47:35: -> Iniciado
D/14:47:36: -> Iniciado
D/14:47:37: -> Iniciado
D/14:47:38: -> Iniciado
D/14:47:38: -> Iniciado
D/14:47:39: -> Iniciado
D/14:47:40: -> Iniciado
D/14:47:41: -> Iniciado
D/14:47:42: -> Iniciado
D/14:47:43: -> Iniciado
D/14:47:43: -> Iniciado
D/14:47:44: -> Iniciado
D/14:47:45: -> Iniciado
D/14:47:46: -> Iniciado
D/14:47:46: -> Iniciado
D/14:47:47: -> Iniciado
D/14:47:48: -> Iniciado
D/14:47:49: -> Iniciado
D/14:47:50: -> Iniciado
I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 3085(212KB) AllocSpace objects, 2(40KB) LOS objects, 1% free, 28MB/28MB, paused 5.805ms total 16.525ms
D/14:47:50: -> Iniciado
D/14:47:51: -> Iniciado
D/14:47:52: -> Iniciado
D/14:47:53: -> Iniciado
D/14:47:54: -> Iniciado
D/14:47:55: -> Iniciado
D/14:47:56: -> Iniciado
D/14:47:57: -> Iniciado
D/14:47:58: -> Iniciado
D/14:47:58: -> Iniciado
D/14:47:59: -> Iniciado
D/14:48:00: -> Iniciado
D/14:48:01: -> Iniciado
D/14:48:02: -> Iniciado
D/14:48:02: -> Iniciado
D/14:48:03: -> Iniciado
D/14:48:04: -> Iniciado
D/14:48:05: -> Iniciado
D/14:48:06: -> Iniciado
D/14:48:07: -> Iniciado
D/14:48:09: -> Iniciado
D/14:48:10: -> Iniciado
D/14:48:11: -> Iniciado
D/14:48:12: -> Iniciado
D/14:48:13: -> Iniciado
D/14:48:13: -> Iniciado
D/14:48:14: -> Iniciado
D/14:48:15: -> Iniciado
D/14:48:16: -> Iniciado
D/14:48:17: -> Iniciado
D/14:48:18: -> Iniciado
D/14:48:19: -> Iniciado
D/14:48:20: -> Iniciado
D/14:48:21: -> Iniciado
D/14:48:22: -> Iniciado
D/14:48:22: -> Iniciado
Application terminated.

E testando no meu celular funcionou corretamente e com pouco tempo de delay para exibir as notificações com o aplicativo fechado e aberto, você pode também chamar um Service ou um IntetService no onReceive.

Comment: Saudações, Rafael. Você publicou exatamente esta resposta aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/305514/5878. Se uma resposta em outra pergunta atende esta, então sinalize como duplicada, não poste a mesma resposta repetidas vezes. Conteúdo duplicado só polui a comunidade.